# Mod_rewrite enabled but not working - ubuntu (file does not exist)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

Im having a problem setting up mod_rewrite. Im using localhost and is on ubuntu.

I already enabled mod_rewrite and also changed the AllowOverride from None to All.

My .htaccess is as simple as this.. since it's not working I wanted to know if it's still not working in its simplest form:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sample.html$ sample1.html
```

When i write sample.html in browser it says "not found"

Comment: Did you restart the apache server?

Comment: Here's a crazy thought... does `sample1.html` exist?

Comment: How about you check the apache logs?

Comment: Did you change AllowOverride in the main config file? Did you enable mod_rewrite (aka did you uncomment it in the main config file and made sure it is in the proper folder? Restarting Apache is not optional when making changes to the main config file. Did you do that? Where is your .htaccess file? Is this the only thing in your .htaccess file?